# Can't upload SOME .png files

Tags: php, html, file-upload

I tried uploading .png files with my image upload function. Some images worked, for example [this one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WVJhZ.png). But for some reason, .png images snapped with Windows Snapshot Tool do not work.

The error message I am getting is: "Sorry, only JPG, JPEG, PNG & GIF files are allowed.", and naturally also "Sorry, your file was not uploaded." (see code below).

I'm sure what I produce with the Windows Snapshot Tool are .png images, so why won't my code accept them as such?

```
<?php
    $target_dir = "i/";
    $target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
    $uploadOk = 1;
    $imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
    // Check if image file is a actual image or fake image
    if(isset($_POST["imgUpload"])) {
        $check = getimagesize($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"]);
        if($check !== false) {
            $uploadOk = 1;
        } else {
            echo "File is not an image.<br>";
            $uploadOk = 0;
        }
        // Check if file already exists
        if (file_exists($target_file)) {
            echo "Sorry, file already exists.<br>";
            $uploadOk = 0;
        }
        // Check file size
        if ($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["size"] > 5000000) {
            echo "Sorry, your file is too large.<br>";
            $uploadOk = 0;
        }
        // Allow certain file formats
        if($imageFileType != "jpg" && $imageFileType != "png" && $imageFileType != "jpeg"
        && $imageFileType != "gif" ) {
            echo "Sorry, only JPG, JPEG, PNG & GIF files are allowed.<br>";
            $uploadOk = 0;
        }
        // Check if $uploadOk is set to 0 by an error
        if ($uploadOk == 0) {
            echo "Sorry, your file was not uploaded.<br>";
        // if everything is ok, try to upload file
        } else {
            $path_parts = pathinfo($target_file);
            $tmpFileName = round(microtime(true));
            $newfilename = $tmpFileName . '.' . $path_parts['extension'];

//Et cetera et cetera
```

I've based my upload code almost entirely of [W3C's](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp) example.
Can anyone explain the problem?

Comment: My psychic debugging skills tell me that your problem is that `"png" != "PNG"`.

Comment: Oh.. Had no idea that matters. I'll try it out. Why are some images PNG and others just png then?

Comment: Christ, that worked. Boy this is embarrassing. You really are psychic. Can .gif come as .GIF and similar aswell?

Comment: Yes; extensions are not always lowercase.

Answer (score 0):

Extensions can have any case.

You need a case-insensitive comparison.